# I can't interact with two tasks on my task bar (notification icons)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, amd-radeon

This is the strangest problem i've ever had. Two of the applications on my taskbar (notification icons) are 90% unresponsive. 90% meaning i can open them (can only close them with right click -> close) and see the main screen for both apps BUT i cannot click ANYTHING on either of them, the buttons will be highlighted but i simply cant click on them. These programs are the Radeon settings application and Malwarebytes settings. MBS popups also cant be interacted with. I only found out about the MBS settings by coincidence because i thought it was strictly a radeon problem but it turns out somethings up with my pc?

Ive tried sfc /scannow 3 times with no problems found. Ive restored my computer to previous update and ive clean uninstalled my graphics drivers (i THOUGHT it was solely radeon at first). This is a problem because when i try to install new drivers i cant click the accept and install button on the radeon window! Just like what was happening in the settings. Small update; I just noticed that when i'm on my desktop and i switch between the programs in question and my desktop, the desktop flickers for a second and this only happens with the aforementioned programs. May or may not be relevant.

What the hell is going on??
This on top of my other thread, i've just been having a bunch of weird ass problems...

I just made the ultimate sacrifice in re-installing windows 7. The problem persists. What a waste of time...

(reposting from Tom's hardware in hopes that i can get some help)

Comment: Side note, when i restart my computer i cant access the taskbar at all until i ctrl-alt-del

Comment: It sounds like these programs are run as administrator while you aren't, or otherwise the programs run in a different userspace.

Comment: @LPChip Nope, i built it from the ground up, its my computer. I just ran the radeon setup as admin as you suggested and the same thing occurs, opens to the "accept and install" screen, button highlights but i can not click it. All the buttons highlight if i mouse over them.(minimize button and exit button)  I can even use the mouse wheel to scroll up and down the terms, but i cant click a single thing.

Comment: I didn't say to run the program as administrator, but that it already runs as admin while you aren't. Your solution does comfirm that something on your account makes it not evaluate as administrator and makes the program unavailable for interaction to you while you still see it. This is similar as to when you have TeamViewer, but not allow it to make changes to the computer (Aka, not run as admin). As soon as a popup for admin pops up and the user clicks yes, you can see it, but not interact with it.

Comment: Scratch what i said earlier, it seems to be stemming from the mouse. a Razer Deathadder. It was by chance that i plugged in the old mouse and than you commented so i went to go try a new user. But then, plugging the razer mouse back in again shows that the problem still occurs. Im using an old mouse now on my first (main account) and everything is working. But i still want to know why in the hell this is happening on the new mouse and only on a few programs.

Comment: The catch is however, the old mouse only works if i restart the computer without the razer plugged in.

Comment: uhhh okay, this is rather embarrassing...The back button on the mouse was stuck. I reinstalled my windows because of a stuck button. Sorry to waste your time @LPChip